# Query with WITH clause and COUNT subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

In the query below, I don't get the results i would expect. Any insights why? How could i reformulate such query to get the desired results?

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(x,y) AS (VALUES(0,ABS(Random()%3)) UNION ALL SELECT x+1, ABS(Random()%3) FROM cnt WHERE x<10),
  i_rnd as (SELECT r1.x, r1.y, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cnt as r2 WHERE r2.y<=r1.y) as idx FROM cnt as r1)
SELECT * FROM i_rnd ORDER BY y;
```

result:

```
| x   | y   | idx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 0   | 3   |
| 5   | 0   | 6   |
| 8   | 0   | 5   |
| 9   | 0   | 4   |
| 10  | 0   | 2   |
| 3   | 1   | 4   |
| 0   | 2   | 11  |
| 2   | 2   | 11  |
| 4   | 2   | 11  |
| 6   | 2   | 11  |
| 7   | 2   | 11  |
```

expected result:

```
| x   | y   | idx |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1   | 0   | 5   |
| 5   | 0   | 5   |
| 8   | 0   | 5   |
| 9   | 0   | 5   |
| 10  | 0   | 5   |
| 3   | 1   | 6   |
| 0   | 2   | 11  |
| 2   | 2   | 11  |
| 4   | 2   | 11  |
| 6   | 2   | 11  |
| 7   | 2   | 11  |
```

In other words, idx should indicate how many rows have y less or equal than the y of row considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use:

```
select cnt.*,
       count(*) over (order by y)
from cnt;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=98f5c70f554d3a4ac2e5fee12026c49d) is a db<>fiddle.

The issue with your code is probably that the CTE is re-evaluated each time it is called, so the values are not consistent -- a problem with volatile functions in CTEs.

Comment: genius! surely must be the re-evaluation of the CTE. Thanks to your suggestion, I can now generate a random sequence on N numbers with a 'fake' rowid, to use in an update query:  `WITH RECURSIVE cnt (x,y) AS ( select 0, Random() UNION ALL SELECT x+1, Random() FROM cnt WHERE x<10), 
p as (select cnt.*, count(*) over (order by y,x) from cnt)
select * from p;`
where the x in `order by y,x` solves the ambiquity in the rare case of random duplicates

Comment: oh, it doesn't work though with sqlite prior to version 3.25, so it will not work on android... that's why i didn't use the most simple ROW_NUMBER for my purpose...

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a pre 3.25 solution?

Comment: @AndrewBloom . . . This question is EXPLICITLY about a version of SQLite that supports window functions.  This is probably much trickier in an earlier version.  I would suggest a temporary table.

Comment: my bad, I tried the query with dbfiddle where there are no db pre 3.25 and the misleading `Schema (SQLite v3.30)` comes from there. I thought if I had to amend the question but your answer is right for the question and so i'll leave it as it is. I'm actually trying a temporary table to bypass the volatility of CTEs. Thanks for your help.